# jQuery Ajax doesn't hit spring boot API

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to call a web service on the server using jQuery Ajax from a web page, it returns 302 (redirect the request to access-denied page). I am adding my code below:

**jQuery Code:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/posts",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    });
```

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Code**

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", 
                        "/css/**",
                        "/js/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
    }
```

and my **accessDeniedHandler** looks like this:

```
@Component
public class LoggingAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {   
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response,
                       AccessDeniedException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        // auth has a value
        if (auth != null) {
           // log
        } 
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/access-denied"); 
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, Why is my Ajax request goes to AccessDeniedHandler?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the csrf token in `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` this method like below.

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

You can refer [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Spring-Security-MVC-program-throw-403-forbidden-for-default-target-url-and-ajax-call) thread for more clarification.

Comment: That works, but I don't want to disable the csrf. instead, I sent the csrf as a header parameter.
         headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': token 
           }
thank you @Alien, your answer was the key to find the solution